# Neutrinos and Weak interaction

Tags: particle-physics, neutrinos, weak-interaction

As a beginner in particle physics I have a small doubt. Do we get neutrinos as a product in any process involving weak interaction? Is emission of a neutrino signature of weak interaction? OR there is a weak interaction process where neutrinos are  not produced?

Comment: Read up on non-leptonic weak interactions, involving hadrons only, like $K^-\to \pi^0~~\pi^-$, covered adequately in most texts, including yours, perhaps? A thousand questions on this site cannot match a good text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A weak interaction which involves only quarks is called a "hadronic weak interaction," because particles made of quarks are collectively called "hadrons." For example, the charged kaon can undergo the hadronic decay $K^+\to\pi^+\pi^0$, the leptonic decay $K^+\to\mu^+\nu_\mu$, or the semi-leptonic decay $K^+\to\pi^0e^+\nu_e$. The neutrino is created to preserve the overall lepton number of zero: an equal number of leptons compared to antileptons, in both the initial and final states.

Neutrinos are furthermore only "produced" in charged current ($W^\pm$) interactions; the neutral current ($Z$) can interact without producing new particles.

Answer (score 3):

E.g. the process $e^+ e^- \to e^+ e^+$ receives a contribution from a virtual $Z^0$ in the $s$-channel (together with the contributions from virtual $\gamma$ and Higgs exchange). Nonleptonic kaon decays are other examples (see the comment by Cosmas Zachos). You find all this in introductory text books on particle physics.

Answer (score 1):

Some additional comments:

1. Weak neutral currents are hard to measure. Consider as generic:

$$ \nu + X \rightarrow \nu' + X^* $$

Both the beam and scattered particle are neutrinos...not easy to detect. Nevertheless, there is a long history:

[https://home.cern/news/news/physics/forty-years-neutral-currents#:~:text=The%20discovery%20of%20weak%20neutral,the%20theory%20of%20neutral%20currents](https://home.cern/news/news/physics/forty-years-neutral-currents#:%7E:text=The%20discovery%20of%20weak%20neutral,the%20theory%20of%20neutral%20currents).

2. With charged leptons, the problem is that the electromagnetic interaction is much stronger than the weak interaction. At tree level, you have a photon amplitude and a $Z$ amplitude:

$$ A = A_{\gamma} + A_Z $$

so what you measure goes like:

$$ \sigma \propto |A_{\gamma}|^2 + |A_Z^2| + (A_{\gamma}^*A_Z + A_Z^*A_{\gamma}) $$

The $|A_Z|^2$ is completely unmeasurable. The interference term leads to parity violation, and can be measured experimentally. There is parity violating electron scattering, probing the quark spin structure; while Moeller scattering and PV in atomic physics probe the Weinberg angle at lower energy scales than colliders.

See:

https://indico.cern.ch/event/570680/contributions/2310195/attachments/1341818/2025976/Beminiwattha_SPIN2016_MOLLER.pdf